# A question about $\operatorname{Tor}_i$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose P'$\to$M is a projective resolution of M. And P'$\bigotimes$C is a complex and the definition of $Tor_i$ is $h^i$(P'$\bigotimes$C). However I am confused about $Tor_i$. As tensor product is right exact thus P'$\bigotimes$C should be exact  except for the right end, then by the definition of exact sequence, ker $f_{i+1}$=im$f_i$, thus $h^i$=ker $f_{i+1}$/im$f_i$ is trivial. What's wrong with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right exactness of a functor only means that short right exact sequences are preserved. Long right exact sequences include short exact sequences, which are only preserved by exact functors. For the functor $- \otimes C$ this means that $\mathrm{Tor}_0(-,C) = - \otimes C$, but not necessarily $\mathrm{Tor}_1(-,C) = 0$. Convince yourself that $\mathrm{Tor}_1(\mathbb{Z}/n,A) = \ker(n : A \to A)$ for abelian groups $A$, which is usually non-zero.

Comment: Yes you are right, I missed something from definitions

Comment: I had made the same mistake at least two times when learning derived functors for the first time.